# SharePoint 2010 flash "SWF" on homepage

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have a homepage on which I want to put a flash banner without using any webpart ..how to do that?

Comment: dont want to show like a web part of list or something...just like a plain website webpage..can't it be rendered inside aspx?

Comment: What did try so far? Can you want to use SharePoint Designer or do you need a WSP package?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your object tag with the swf on the master page directly or you can create a System.Web.UI.Control subclass and override the Render method for rendering the object using the control on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own [Master Page or Page Layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497650.aspx) with your flash banner